# Unable to read data from InputStream on live process

Tags: java, process, inputstream, nio

I'm executing a shell command from java using ProcessBuilder. My shell command is a utility which is running always once invoked. 
Trying to read command output using InputStream, as it is live process read() blocking. 
Tried creating worker thread for reading purpose. But still read() is never coming back.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(); 

processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", "<my utility start command>"); 
Process ps = processBuilder.start(); ReadableByteChannel inputChannel = Channels.newChannel(ps.getInputStream()); ByteBuffer byteBuffer = 
ByteBuffer.allocate(1024); Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII"); while (inputChannel.read(byteBuffer) > 0) { byteBuffer.rewind(); 
System.out.print(charset.decode(byteBuffer)); byteBuffer.flip();
}
```

Comment: in future , post your formatted code in question. Not as a comment.

Comment: Sure. Thank you.

Comment: Can any one answer this ?